# Particles are not in contact with object

Tags: particles

I've been watching Andrew Prices tutorial on "how to make a cave in blender". So now I'm trying to put mushrooms in the cave as a particle system to spread them along the floor of the cave.

[image]

Unfortunately, as shown by the red arrows, some of the mushrooms are not in contact with the cave at all, and are hovering either above or below the cave floor.

Is this some kind of setting that makes particles placement random? Anyway, here's the [.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38384) file if you wanna take a look.

Also, I wouldn't mind if I got some overall feedback too!

Comment: This isn't the place to ask for feedback on an image, but I have answered in respect to the rest of the question.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I don't mind if you would like to comment on other flaws in my scene, know what I mean?

Comment: I know what you mean, but that sort of discussion is better suited to http://blenderartists.org/

Comment: no problem! I gotta get good connections on the blender community anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is the child particles which are being placed above or below the surface. I found that changing the 'Children' type on the particle system from 'Simple' to 'Interpolated' created a more accurate result, though I'm not quite sure *why* 'Simple' children wouldn't respect the location as much:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! The mushrooms are stuck to the ground now but... In the tutorial Andrew uses simple children yet the mushrooms are on the right place... I can't tell for sure since his mushrooms are much smaller.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem feel free to 'accept' this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information.

Comment: alright! thx for the help :)