# Hair Particles / Gras poise over plane in camera

Tags: particles, camera

I have some troubles understanding camera in blender.

I take a mesh plane object and set up a simple particle system.

In Orthogonal Mode the scene looks like expected. I put three images in one because I am not allowed to upload more than 2 images.

[image: Three in one. Orth View, Camera View and Settings tab]

In Camera View the stupid problem happen: Some hairs are above the plane. I upload you the rendered image to see it better.
[image: Rendered Image which shows some crazy hairs upper the plane]

Thank you!

Comment: The model should be view-indipendent (except if you specifically build it for being not). Are you using *Simpe Children* option?

Comment: No I Using _Children_ -> _None_. Should I switch to _Simple Children_?

Comment: Sorry guy, I just see that: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39487/particles-are-not-in-contact-with-object?rq=1 give some help but if someone can explain it I will be happy otherwise I will close this question in some days.